# How can I unselect a feature in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, features, select

I am able to identify the selected features on my map using the following line:

```
vector_layer.selectedFeatures
```

I would like to be able to deselect this feature using a standalone function (not an event-handler). I've tried using the functions `unselect()` and `unselectAll()` unsuccessfully and can't find any examples of this approach.

I am aware that clicking on the selected object can be used to `unselect`. In this case I want a programmatic solution.

Comment: It's not quite what I am trying to do but `unSelect` issues are discussed here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/486

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I have seen these and tried to adapt them for my grid layer. As far as I can tell, every example for selecting features involved creating the features first. I have not (yet) seen a working example where an existing layer is loaded and the user selects features from this layer. I am starting to think that selectFeature only works for vectors that you create on the fly. I hope this is not true or else I am in trouble. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OpenLayers 2:
You can unselect features with unselect and unselectAll methods of SelectFeature control:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer);
...
map.addControls([selectControl]);
selectControl.activate();

// unselect any specific feature...
selectControl.unselect(vectorLayer.features[0]);
// ...or all features
selectControl.unselectAll();
```

If this doesn't work, there's probably bug in your code.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHxnh/1/

Comment: I don't see that in the documentation... but it works!

Answer (score 1):

**Openlayers unselecting Objects - various methods**

> Use the shift key to select multiple features. Use the ctrl key to
>   toggle selection on features one at a time. Note: the "clickout"
>   option has no effect when "hover" is selected

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html

> click out to unselect features

Comment: Sorry, should have added the word programmatic. I want to `unselect` using a function, not a click.