# Having trouble selecting polygon from existing layer (using OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature)

Tags: openlayers-2, features, select

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am not a programmer, so that is my first roadblock. *ha*

The problem:
I have an existing polygon layer and I am trying to select one of the polygons. This has got to be one of the simplest tasks, but I am unable to figure out how to do it. I am trying to follow the methods in the OpenLayers Beginner's Guide, but so far nothing has worked out:

```
var select_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
     legal_land_descriptor,
     {
    multiple: false,
    toggle: true,
    multipleKey: 'shiftKey'
     }
);

map.addControl(select_feature_control);
select_feature_control.activate();
```

Should this not allow me to select a polygon?  I did manage to query the polygons by clicking on them, and now I am just trying to select one of the polygons, Argh!

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to create the legal_land_descriptor layer?

Answer (score 1):

probably you should try first multiple: hover. One way is that you try http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature.html, so copy this to your pc and delete what you don't need, just leave the create/select buttons and start testing, that's a very good to start learning both javascript and openlayers. Also, take a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41017/how-can-i-unselect-a-feature-in-openlayers)

Comment: The link below is dead, please update...